# How to add class to Form in Yii framework?

Tags: css, forms, class, yii

I have a form in Yii, and I want to add a class to the form :

```
<form class="subscribe_form" action="#" method="post">
```

I tried this but it's not working :

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                                'class'=>'subscribe_form',
                        'id'=>'mail-list-addmail-form',
                        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false
                    )); ?>
```

Thanks for helping me!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an htmlOptions property, like this:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                        'id'=>'mail-list-addmail-form',
                        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                          'class'=>'subscribe_form',
                        )
                    )); ?>
```

from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#htmlOptions-detail

Answer (score 0):

**htmlOptions:** `additional HTML attributes that should be rendered for the form tag.`

**htmlOptions:** there is commonly through all HTML helpers `CHtml`, `CActiveForm` and you can set the custom HTML options in this property.