# How to add classes in Yii form button submit

Tags: php, html, yii

I have this line of code for create profile button :

```
 <?php echo $form->bsBtnSubmit(Yii::t('idea', "Create Profile")); ?>
```

I want to add these classes for the button's styling:

```
btn btn-sd btn-sd-green full-width
```

I tried as below:

```
 <?php echo $form->bsBtnSubmit(Yii::t('idea', "Create Profile", 'class'=>'btn btn-sd btn-sd-green full-width')); ?>
```

but it's not working. How can I add these classes to my button above?

Comment: This will help you :- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764118/how-to-add-class-to-form-in-yii-framework]

Comment: What is `bsBtnSubmit()` method?

Answer (score 0):

using Html :

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Create Profile', ['class' => 'btn btn-sd btn-sd-green full-width', 'value'=>'create_add', 'name'=>'submit']) ?>
```

using CHtml

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Create Profile', array('class' => 'btn btn-sd btn-sd-green full-width')); ?>
```

Comment: but how can I apply to my button... <?php echo $form->bsBtnSubmit(Yii::t('idea', "Create Profile")); ?> I tried doing this but it doesn't work <?php echo $form->bsBtnSubmit(Yii::t('idea', "Create Profile", array('class' => 'btn btn-sd btn-sd-green full-width'))); ?>

Comment: can you explain me what is bsBtnSubmit ? if you used any package than let me know